# How to serve pages inside a phonegap app from a from instead of file://

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I would like to serve the pages in my phonegap app from a domain.
Like a local server inside the app.

The basic app example serve the pages from file:// and one of our integrating does not whitelist it correctly.

This is not related [Cordova Whitelist](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't.

Although it is *possible* to host apps from a domain, it is extremely risky and presents a poor user experience in the case of no/flaky network connectivity, and app stores may reject the app. If you must update your app outside of the app store review process, you can use various code push solutions which push code to the device instead.

- Risky: MITM attacks; no ability to check certificate signature prior to download; how do you handle a partial/corrupt download of the page, etc.
- Poor UX: If no network connection, nothing is present to tell the user about that. If flaky network, then the app may load for a long time, or timeout, etc., and again, there's nothing to alert the user.
- App store rejection: Primarily Apple here, but they tend to reject apps that are viewed as wrappers for websites. Your app must also alert the user when there is no network connection if one is required.

Comment: It could be a local server, not necessarily through network. I just need a domain.